# Convert string to number with zero decimal and not to be a string

Tags: php

I'm working with eBay API and for some stupid reason prices have to be in double format even if zero.

For example:
I have a price of value 100
I need to send it to eBay as 100.00 but it must NOT be a string.

No matter what I've tried I get float(100) and not 100.00

I've tried (double), (int), doubleval() without any success.

number_format is out of the question because output is a string.

I've spend way too much time trying to get this right.

Please help.

LE:
Value passed to eBay: [value] => 120
Returned error: You have entered invalid start price or Buy It Now price.

I'm using ebay-sdk-php and the type I'm supposed to pass is documented [here](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Types/DoubleType.php)

[eBay required type to be passed](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/simpleTypes.html#double)

Comment: What is the API call exactly? An url to the documentation would be of help.

Comment: Type declaration: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/simpleTypes.html#double

Comment: Dear me, that's an XML call? But XML is a string.

Comment: @akond it is a string but I'm using a php library to format the request. Check my changes in the question.

Comment: @Ovidiu the definition in PHP of `0.00` is that it must be a string. A floated version of that would simply be `0`

Comment: @RobbieAverill so it's impossible to have it how I need?

Comment: No, more likely is that you _can_ use a string, it's just how you're using it :) I don't know enough about this SDK to be able to say any more sorry

Answer (score 1):

Formated number types don't exist in PHP. They also wouldn't make any sense without a specific context.

But the SDK you use provides custom types for creating the XML you send to eBay. For price it should be:

```
new Types\AmountType(['value' => 100]);
```

If that doesn't work, post the code that produces the error. I doubt anybody can help without it.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  $var  = (float) number_format(float(100),2)
```

Comment: convert that string to float?

Comment: That's exactly my problem. How to convert a string to a float with two zero decimals?